# How can I create a view in mysql

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

The SQL looks like this:

```
select * 
  from A 
 where A.id in (select id 
                  from B 
                 where b.date>'2015-01-01') 
 group by a.id;
```

`b.data>'2015-01-01'` is a dynamic condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use subqueries in a View, but you can join the tables to get what you need:

```
create view my_view as
select A.*
from A
    inner join B on A.id = B.id
where B.date > '2015-01-01'
group by A.id;
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"You can't use subqueries in a View"_. My example above (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61c0/1) worked pretty well?! Is there any restriction to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only use this workaround:

1. create a function that represents your dynamic value:

   ```
   create function param() returns date deterministic no sql return @param;
   ```
2. create the view:

   ```
   create or replace view myView as (
     select * 
       from A 
      where A.id in (select id 
                       from B 
                      where b.date>param()) 
      group by a.id);
   ```
3. select values

   ```
   select v.* 
     from (select @param:=str_to_date('01-1-2015','%d-%m-%Y') p) param , myView v;
   ```

***p.s.***: I fixed a small typo above; removed a semi-colon. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61c0/1) you have an example.